# Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate while installing tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, ffmpeg

I`m a german studant. For the school I have to make a physics or chemistry project, I decided to install tensorflow on a raspberry pi to train a object detection modal. 
But there is an error I don´t understand.
'Package 'ffmpeg' has no insstallation candidate.'

I tried to install ffmpeg from source but this didn´t help

I use a raspberry pi 4 4gb ram.
With Raspbain 10 (buster)

Answer (score -1):

Try installling `libav-tools` package, `apt-get install libav-tools`  and  `avconv` command instead of ffmpeg. libav is a fork of ffmpeg

Appropriate sources
[Ubuntu source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04)
[pi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=125367)

Comment: I had build ffmpeg from source and had installed the libav-tools before,
but it didn´t work.

I try to install Tensorflow with the following command: 

tensorflow/tools/ci_build/ci_build.sh PI \
    tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh
For Python2. 

Acording to the instructions:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_rpi

Can I change there the command to avconv?

Comment: I dont know about that, I ll upvote the question, somebody else can answer it. I think you should ask this question in rasperry pi forum rather than here